# (Android) DrawerLayout не запускается на втором активити

Tags: android, drawerlayout

Как же все таки равнодушным можно оставаться к программированию для Android? Ни одной функции просто взять и реализовать! Ни одной!

На этот раз есть абсолютно два одинаковых активити.xml .

activity_city.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".mainActivity">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base.AppBarOverlay"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/etSearch"
                    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                    android:hint="Название города"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/secondary_text" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context=".mainActivity"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
                    android:divider="@color/divider"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_city2"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_city2_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_sfera.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".mainActivity">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base.AppBarOverlay"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/etSearch"
                    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                    android:hint="Название города"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/secondary_text" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context=".mainActivity"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
                    android:divider="@color/divider"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_city2"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_city2_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

В mainActivity.java :

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        if (mSettings.contains("city")) {

            cityOption = mSettings.getString("city", null);
            if (cityOption != null) {
                if (hasConnection(getBaseContext())) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sfera);
                    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);
                    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_title));
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        }
                    });

                    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                    toggle.syncState();

                    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

                    etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
                    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            sferaAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                        }
                    });
                    get_sferaList();
                } else {
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout_nointernet);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (hasConnection(getBaseContext())) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_city);
                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);
                toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_title));
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                });

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();

                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

                etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
                etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        cityAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    }
                });
                get_cityList();
            } else {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_nointernet);
            }

        }
    }
```

То есть если в настройках есть название города, показываем activity_sfera, если в настройках названия города нет, то показываем activity_city. Почему если setContentView(R.layout.activity_city) работает, а если setContentView(R.layout.activity_sfera) завершает приложение с ошибкой:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Хотите сказать, вы программно во время работы программы меняете `setContentView()` в зависимости от настроек?Или я не правильно понял, и он у вас как установился(сетКонтент) так и статичен во время всей работы?

Comment: В зависимости от настроек устанавливаем setContentView()

Comment: Кстати, такая же ошибка наблюдается , если запустить activity_sfera как новую активити, через startActivity()

Answer (score 2):

У вас неверно спроектирована архитектура приложения.

Начну с того, что действия, которые вы выполняете в `onResume()` - нужно перенести в `onCreate()`, поскольку пользователь после остановки и возобновления приложения будет видеть каждый раз новые данные(пересоздание объектов).

Во вторых, в разработке `setContentView()` используется **единожды** для *каждой* активити.

`setContentView()` должен устанавливаться **до** действий в активити, иначе рискуете нарваться на NPE.

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        if (mSettings.contains("city")) {

            cityOption = mSettings.getString("city", null);
            if (cityOption != null) {
                if (hasConnection(getBaseContext())) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sfera);
                    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);
                    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_title));
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Как было сказано выше - `setContentView()` для каждой активити должен быть один. Без манипуляций, подобных этой:

```
 etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        cityAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    }
                });
                get_cityList();
            } else {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_nointernet);
            }

        }
    }
```

Хотите указать, что у пользователя отсутствует интернет? Можете использовать уйму других способов, начиная с отображения простого диалога, или использования фрагментов.

Насчет ошибки. Для меня этот код трудночитаемый, но уверен, что проблема в изначально неправильном подходе.

Comment: Я бы тоже этот код трудно прочитал, если бы сам его не написал, уверяю Вас, при запуске приложения setContentView() вызывается единожды (layout_nointernet содержит кнопку но нажатию на которую вызывается finish() и затем startActivity(), а в зависимости от настроек тоже запускается только один setContentView ). А что касается архитектуры, в ответ на ваш первый комментарий я написал, что эта же ошибка вылетает даже в том случае, если мы запустим activity_sfera как отдельную активити. Сейчас попробую перенести в onCreate, но сомневаюсь, что поможет.

Comment: Как и предполагалось, перенос в onCreate метод ничего не дал.

Comment: @Новичок дал более правильный подход архитектурный, в будущем скажете (возможно) спасибо. Попробуйте смоделировать, когда 1 setContentView(); работает, затем сделайте кнопку, что переводит на другую активити, с такой же разметкой.
Короче говоря разделите на две, чтобы работали, затем поэтапно переносите.

Comment: Вам, как и мне, это покажется странным, но изначально у меня было все раздельно. На втором активити вылетала эта ошибка, что заставило меня объединить это все в активити, где все работало. если это приложение запустить так, как оно спроектирвоано у меня то: 1. Если нет нужных нам настроек, то по условию запуститься activity_city, и все будет работать (точно так же , как было при раздельных активити; 2. Если настройка искомая есть, то по условию должно выполниться setContentView(R.layout.activity_sfera) и вылетает с указанной выше ошибкой, как и в случае с раздельными активити.

Comment: Содержание обеих активити ИДЕНТИЧНОб в чем Вы можете убедиться

Comment: @Новичок у вас в setContentView() где city находится сфера, и наоборот. Это так и задумано?

Comment: Да, то есть проверяется условие, если Название города раньше выбиралось, тогда пропускаем этот шаг и запускаем активити с выбором сферы, если же название города еще не выбиралось, то запускаем активити с выбором города

Comment: Запустил debug. DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); после выполнения этой строчки drawer = null

Comment: И что бы вы думали? В манифесте расположил активити в следующем порядке <activity
            android:name=".sferaActivity"...>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".mainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            ..>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> и Drawer создан. Я сплю или это бред какой-то?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, не знаю, кто еще может столкнуться с таким бредом, но проблема решилась, когда я в манифесте поменял местами активити.